# display data from two table by matching id codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

**customer table**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu4Ti.png)

**siteproducts table**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCs4s.png)

I want to display the records of currently logged in users product deatils
ex: customer no 15 is logged in then records should displayed only of him

**Model**

```
public function customerparcelstatus()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('siteproducts');
        $this->db->join('customer', 'siteproducts.customer_id=customer.customer_id');
        //$this->db->order_by('customer.customer_id');
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public function custparcelstatus()
    {
        $this->load->model('orbitcustomer_model');
        $data['parcellistview'] = $this->orbitcustomer_model->customerparcelstatus();
        $this->load->view('customer/customer_dashboard', $data);
    }
```

**view**

```
<tbody>
<?php if (!empty($parcellistview)) { foreach($parcellistview as $user) {?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $user['customer_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['customer_code']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['product_code']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['received_date']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['received_from']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['tracking_ref_no']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['parcel_status']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['parcel_note']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } } else { ?>
<tr>
    <td>Norecords Found</td>
</tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retrieve records only related to currently logged in customer by using where clause on query like below.

```
$this->db->where('customer_id', $customer); //currently logged in user
```